# MySQL Question about scheduling

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to ask about scheduling, is there any MySQL command for scheduling. For example, I want to insert a data into the DB. Can I write a sql statement to hold it for some time, or maybe I insert this data in some scheduled time, for example, tomorrow 8:00 a.m.

I know these can be done by programming, but I want to do it in SQL command, is it possible to do so? If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduling background jobs is not part of the SQL command set.  So it is down to each database vendor to provide their own extension.  In Oracle it is a PL/SQL package, `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (or `DBMS_JOB` in older versions).  In MYSQL it would appear to be [the Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html), which use SQL syntax.

**Edit**

As Paul Dixon has pointed out the Event Scheduler is a relatively recent extension to MySQL (I'm not a MySQL expert, so forgive if this is not helpful to you).

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 5.1.6+ has an [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html).

If you're using an earlier version, you could write a little script which executed the desired SQL, and schedule it with [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix_command%29),[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i).

Without more detail about exactly what you're trying to do this is a good place to start.