# Does MySQL have time-based triggers?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, cron

I would like to execute a procedure periodically, how to do that in MySQL?

Comment: You can try this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460066/mysql-question-about-scheduling

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have MySQL 5.1 you can use events.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 8):

MySQL allow this with the Event Scheduler :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html