# Database suspension for 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, database

How to suspend a row in Mysql database for 10minutes... After 10minutes that database row must be recovered to the normal stage...

Comment: What does it mean to suspend a row?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "suspend a row"?  Or, for that matter, "recovered to the normal stage"?

Comment: are you trying to block write to a particular record?

Comment: I suggest that you add new column with a visibility value. You can change the value for 10 minutes and than change it back. But it would mean that you would have to rewrite your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to do something a wrong way. What are you trying to achieve. I know no way of "suspending a row". You can just copy a row you want to suspend to the new table and remove it from original table. and then do reverse action based on timely event: [Does MySQL have time-based triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers)