# Updating different rows based on time?

Tags: mysql, events, postgresql, time

What is the best way to update tables based on time in MySQL or PostGre ?

For example I have a database with the following records.

```
ColumnA  StartTime  EndTime
123      02:05:01   02:06:01   
456      02:06:01   02:07:01
```

Is it possible to update the values of the two columns based on the EndTime column, possibly a time event? I tried using cronjobs but I think it is not suitable for time specific events(seconds) specially if the database has a large number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to wrap things in a case, if that's what you're meaning:

```
update foo
set ColumnA = case
    when EndTime < now() then 321
    else 654
    end,
    StartTime = case
    ...
    end
where ...
```

Comment: thnx for the suggestion but that's not what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use Mysql Events, If you are using 5.1

Here is a linked solution [Does MySQL have time-based triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers)

Comment: Thank you for this one. Anyone is there a similar tool such as this in Postgresql?