# Is it okay to create a cron job to delete my data in mysql databse?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I have a situation that i wanted to delete some of my database records after a given date. At the moment I am using the manual way to run a php file each and every day to delete all older records from my database. I have heard about **cron jobs**.

I have decided to go for cron jobs.

Is it a good choice to make this as a cron job? Are there any pros and cons I have to think about?

Comment: @vinu If the data you want to delete after a given date then just use cron job. This is the way. And about the pros and cons , each thing has its pros and cons, but it depends on situation. In your situation their is no cons.

Comment: Cron is the good way to go, but if data are customer related, we normally don't do hard delete, we do soft delete like changing status, or moving records to some archive table so that it will be useful for future reference

Comment: You can also use mySQL triggers to do the same [Time based triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers)

Comment: Thanks for your opinions.I am going to use cron jobs.Please provide your comment as an answer so i can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron is the good way to go, but if data are customer related, we normally don't do hard delete, we do soft delete like changing status, or moving records to some archive table so that it will be useful for future reference.

If your mysql database space is limited definitely go for cron jobs to delete the records. But if you have huge or unlimited mysql database space in the server, you can use Cron jobs to transfer old records to archive table. This will be the safe option because you have all the data.

Also, if you have to delete it anyway, before deleting, in cron, you can write a code to automatically backup your database and emailed it to you, This way you can safely delete the records without having any worries.

Answer (score 2):

If the data you want to delete after a given date then just use cron job. This is the way. And about the pros and cons , each thing has its pros and cons, but it depends on situation. In your situation their is no cons.

Comment: While it's the right answer - there's always a con! In this case, it's when the cron stops working (unless you get it to notify you each time, which becomes a pain). So either keep notifications running, or remember to check occasionally that it's still working. They are not "set and forget", unfortunately.