# What's the best way to automate running MySQL scripts on several databases on a daily basis?

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, ruby

What's the best way to automatically query several dozen MySQL databases with a script on a nightly basis? The script usually returns no results, so I'd ideally have it email or notify me if any are ever returned.

I've looked into PHP, Ruby and Python for this, but I'm a little stumped as to how best to handle this.

Comment: which OS are we talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MySQL have time-based triggers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's a lot of options for the actual script execution, in the end they all boil down to `cron` as @squiguy said. Cron is the de facto task scheduler, allowing you to run any automated task at any time.

Just put your queries in a file, save it as .sql somewhere, and add something like this to your cron (run `crontab -e`) to run it every night at 3:30:

```
30 3 * * * /usr/bin/mysql -u<user> -p<pass> <dbname> < /var/scripts/myscript.sql
```

Then add a line to cron to notify you by email:

```
MAILTO=mymail@address.com
```

In crons always use absolute paths to all files and executables. Run `which mysql` to find out the absolute path for the mysql executable.

Alternatively you could also run a PHP script like this, and use `ob_start` to catch all output, then `mail` to send it by email, or something similar in any other language like Ruby, C++, Python or for all anyone cares LISP or COBOL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only one can answer this question is you. All 3 examples you gave can do what you need to do with cron to automate the job. But the best script language to be used is the one you are most comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a stored procedure, then use events:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html

Else, you can use cron:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

If you need to call a PHP script which does not work from the CLI, or a CGI, use the cron to call the text browser lynx and pass it the URL of the script:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx