# Is this sort of a thing possible in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have timestamps in the following format in a table

```
time_stamp        day_chan1 day_chan2 day_chan3 
2014-06-03 00:01:00  0           0      0
2014-06-03 00:02:00  0           2      1
2014-06-03 00:03:00  1           4      3
2014-06-03 00:04:00  2           7      4
```

and I need to run a loop between the timestamps for every 30 minutes and if there is not timestamp existing for that time, i want to append the day_chan1,day_chan2 and day_chan3 values from the previous timestamp something like the one below

```
start at 2014-06-03 00:00:00 
      if 2014-06-03 00:30:00 exists, 
        proceed to 2014-06-03 01:00:00 
      else insert 2014-06-03 00:30:00 to table and  insert values of 2013-06-03 00:00:00 to the table
```

I am not sure on where to start anymore about this. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to make a script for that.

Comment: i think you can use time based trigger - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers

Comment: Do you want this done to an existing table?  Or is this an ongoing process you want to run, say, every 30 minutes?