# Mysql database - How to make it update every sunday at 23:59

Tags: php, database

So i have this project going on and I've been looking into it a bit myself, but nothing I've done so far have worked automatically. What i want is a method of automatically updating my table without having to manually executing the command by loading the site.

Comment: Use cron tab and run cron script.

Comment: If you can do it directly in the database, then use the events of MySQL

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers

Comment: JFYI, your database is called mysql, not mysqli.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a page as normal php function with whatever you want do update

set cron tab  in your server using **crontab -e**

and then edit the cronjob like this

```
59 23 * * 0 /var/www/somedirectory/somephpfile.php
```

cron tab run the code once at sunday 11.59 pm  each sunday

description for above code

```
[Minute] [Hour] [Day] [Month] [Day of week (0 =sunday to 6 =saturday)] [Command]
```

here is crontab  [reference](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is, in your config.php where you connect to the database, set up a function that will check a DATETIME field in your DB, and if now > lastUpdate + 7days, do your updating and set the field to now().

This way, whenever any php script is executed, it will check this and act accordingly.

It's not a very healthy approach, but it avoids using cron jobs if you are for some reason unable to use them.

```
function regularUpdate()
{
    $lastUpdate = $mysqlconnector->query("select last_update from your_table");
    if(time() > strtotime($lastUpdate)+(60*60*24*7))
    {
        //do your updating
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL event to schedule a job: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html