# Database which can remove records automatically by checking date column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Suppose there is a database which contains a table that has date and events column, there are total 10 records now I want that the records which are older then the current date should automatically be deleted and the present date records should be present in the database so as the future records should also be present, does anyone know something like this or can help me how to achieve this. any references would be helpful. I am open to php, phpmyadmin, sql. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MySQL have time-based triggers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402097/does-mysql-have-time-based-triggers)

Answer (score 1):

First it's too broad. You can consider using [`MySQL Event Scheduler`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) for this purpose. Which you can set to run on every 24 hours and delete all records less than `NOW()`

Comment: can you point some references or tutorials where I can learn this?

Comment: whenever I am trying to turn on event in phpmyadmin its saying I need super privileges to do that now how can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Activate event support :

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Add sheduler :

```
DELIMITER |
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `clear_old_rows`|
CREATE EVENT `clear_old_rows`
    ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT 'clear all rows < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    DO
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM tablename WHERE date < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
    END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: whenver I try to activate event it says I need super privileges to do so now who i get that??

Comment: Must be logged in as root . `mysql -u root -p'rootpass'`