# Executing an SQL query every hour

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i make the following query execute each hour automatically?

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name='MYTABLE'
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

Comment: I really want to help you, but your question is very broad and unclear. Why do you need to execute it? What are you willing to find? What do you want it to do? What is your platform?

For blind executtion, you can use an event. If you want something more out of it - edit your question.

Comment: Even with the event scheduler in mysql the above query does not make sense unless the count is stored somewhere.

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460066/mysql-question-about-scheduling

Comment: @A.Abramov mysql node_module, the purpose of the query is not relevant

Comment: Mysql node module is just a bridge between the node and mysql, if you want the query to be run every hour you need to create an event in mysql server and it will do its job.

Answer (score 4):

Usually in a DBMS exist some schedule of instrument. In Oracle the instrument is DBMS_SCHEDULER.
MySQL same have scheduler. You should check global variable event_scheduler=1. Then you can create schedule:

```
CREATE EVENT 'new_event'
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
  ENABLE
  COMMENT ''  DO
call new_proc();
```

where `new_proc()` is procedure with your query.